# File download with application authorization

Tags: php, nginx, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony 1.4 application with an admin backend, and I would like to make some pdf / images available to authenticated users only. The authentication process is handled by symfony.

How can I make sure only authenticated users can download the files, even files exceeding php's memory_limit setting?

The web server I use is nginx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`X-Sendfile`](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) (/`X-Accel-Redirect`), nginx will serve the file after the PHP script sends the appropriate headers and ends. [This seems a proper explanation](http://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/).

greg0ire > Here is my implementation with symfony 1.4 and nginx:

1. create a directory named "secure" under web
2. configure nginx like this:
3. create a symfony route
4. create a symfony action

**Nginx configuration**:

```
location /secure/ {
    internal;
  }
```

**Symfony routing**

```
SecureDownload:
  url: /anything-you-want-but-secure/:filename
  options:
    segment_separators: ['/'] # filenames often contain dots
  params:
    module: YourModule
    action: secureDownload
```

**Symfony action**

```
<?php
class SecureDownloadAction extends sfAction
{
  public function execute($request)
  {
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader(
      "X-Accel-Redirect",
      "/secure/" . $request->getParameter('filename'));
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader(
      "Content-Disposition",
      "attachement; filename=". $request->getParameter('filename'));
    return sfView::HEADER_ONLY;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what I'm looking for!

Comment: @greg0ire are you sure the header is well send and then nginx serve the file? I tried to implement such behavior with `X-Sendfile` on Lighttpd but never got the right header send using symfony ..

Comment: @jok: I won't be able to check that with firebug, will I? I did make other checks though: I get a 404 when asking for `/secure/file.txt`, and symfony asks for authentication before I can access `/anything-you-want-but-secure/file.txt`, so it seems to work pretty well.